# Hibernate Upgrade to v6 (Spring Boot 3) - "Named type [interface java.util.List] did not implement BasicType nor UserType"

Tags: spring, hibernate, upgrade

After upgrading to Spring Boot 3 / Hibernate 6, I am getting exceptions during Spring application / test startup.

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@15ec3c0c testClass = ....`

`Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Named type [interface java.util.List] did not implement BasicType nor UserType`

Problem can be traced / debugged down to a `List<String>` entity property, which is using an AttributeConverter for storing it as a comma-separated string in the (MySQL) DB (TEXT field).

The converter:

```
@Converter
class StringListToStringConverter : AttributeConverter<List<String>, String> {
....
}
```

The entity:

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class MyInstance<T>(
...

@Column(name = "iface_ids", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
@Convert(converter = StringListToStringConverter::class)
var interfaceIds: List<String> = emptyList()

...
)
```

This has been working nicely before with Spring Boot 2.7.x / Hibernate 5.x.

Do you think there is another solution than writing a custom type (and thus removing/replacing the AttributeConverter) in this case?

Kind Regards,
dom

Expecting it to actually work OOTB, the AttributeConverter solution looks so clean&simple for this purpose compared to a custom type implementation that I don't really want to change that.

Comment: I just tested your code in H6 and it worked for me. Of course I didn't mess about with any Spring stuff.

Comment: Looks like a bug in Hibernate, possibly [HHH-16122](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16122)